# How can I establish a URB_BULK in endpoint (endpoint 3) with pyserial?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm using pyserial to communicate with usb serial device (LG LS970 in download mode), using the qcserial driver on /dev/ttyACM0. My problem is that I can not establish a URB_BULK in endpoint (x.3). The Serial.read() just listen back on the URB_BULK out as far as I can tell. Is there a way to open a URB_BULK in endpoint with pyserial or am I going to have to switch to c for this?

I've got a wireshark log of the device communicating with it's proprietary windows software from inside a vm, and I know it is suppose to open two connections to the device for I/O.

I was hopping to just use pyserial for this to make it cross platform.

So far here is what I am trying to do:

```
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600, timeout=3)
ser.write('\x01\xf1\xe1\x7e')
print ser.read()
ser.write('\x29\x01\x00\x31\x40\x7e')
print ser.read()
ser.write('\x06\x4e\x95\x7e')
print ser.read()
ser.write('\x2f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1a\xc3\x7e')
print ser.read()
ser.write('\x30\xfb\xc1\x7e')
print ser.read()
```

I know the expected return on the URB_BULK in from the device for each write, but I don't see any BULK in from the device when I am sniffing the usb connection. I do see the device confirming that it received the data though.
I know the expected output from these

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here? Thanks!

Comment: pyserial shouldn't need to know about usb endpoints, it just uses the tty driver as exposed by the kernel.  Usually for a CDC/ACM device there is a bulk in/out for data transfer, and an interrupt endpoint for control.  What device are you using?

Comment: I'm using a LG Optimus G in download mode. I've added some of the code I'm using. I've verified the baudrate with what it is in windows using the LGNPST software, which is what I'm trying to implement. I also know that pyserial is sending the hex correct, as I'm looking at the dump via usbmon and wireshark and it's identical to what I see using the lgnpst software via vmware. The only difference is my read's don't return anything and in wireshark I don't see a bulk in endpoint.